# Двенадцать запятых в предложении. Все ли нужны?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, вводные-слова, как, сложное-предложение

*Завтра (впрочем, это будет сегодня), если даст Бог, я пойду к батюшке [Варсонофию Оптинскому], поговорю, авось разъяснит хоть немного, да, как человек уже пожилой и, по-видимому, искренно верующий, даст, может быть, добрый совет.*
[Никон Оптинский, преподобный. Дневник. 1907–1910 гг.](http://predanie.ru/nikon-optinskiy-prepodobnyy/audio/264455-tetrad-pervaya-fragment-1/)

Я запуталась в своих сомнениях и рассуждениях (*впрочем, если даст Бог, авось, да, как*).
Как вы считаете, правильна ли пунктуация в предложении?

Answer (score 3):

*Завтра (впрочем, это будет сегодня), если даст Бог, я пойду к батюшке [Варсонофию Оптинскому], поговорю, авось разъяснит хоть немного да, как человек уже пожилой и, по-видимому, искренно верующий, даст, может быть, добрый совет.*

Все запятые на месте, кроме перед "да": при однородных членах с неповторяющимся соединительным союзом **да = и** (*авось разъяснит **да** даст добрый совет*) запятая не ставится.

*Впрочем* — вводное, *если даст бог* — придаточное условное предложение.

*Пойду к батюшке  поговорю* — запятая по выбору автора, как он употребил:
разговорное сказуемое "пойду поговорю" (тогда нет запятой) или два действия, два однородных сказуемых — сначала пойду, а там уже поговорю.

После "авось" нет запятой, потому что это частица.

*Как человек уже пожилой и, по-видимому, искренно верующий* — обособленное распространённое **приложение**, выраженное конструкцией с КАК,  обосабливается с двух сторон. *По-видимому, может быть* — вводные.

Так что всё верно, кроме одной запятой. Но если иметь в виду, что это речь персонажа, конструкция разговорная, возможно и её объяснить как запятую, отделяющую присоединительную конструкцию: ведь здесь возможна пауза, речь как бы прерывается, он говорит медленно, в раздумье, а потом добавляется информация о добром совете.

Answer (score 3):

**Завтра (впрочем, это будет сегодня), если даст Бог, я пойду к батюшке [Варсонофию Оптинскому], поговорю,  авось разъяснит хоть немного, // да, как человек уже пожилой и, по-видимому, искренно верующий, даст, может быть, добрый совет.**

Нет вопросов к этому тексту, практически все запятые на месте (спорной является только запятая перед союзом ДА).

1) Дневниковая запись, состоит **из двух смысловых блоков**. Союз ДА расположен на границе блоков, перед ним делается пауза и обозначается запятой.

Грамматику можно объяснить следующим образом: это или соединительный союз между предложениями, или присоединительный союз между однородными сказуемыми.

2) Оборот ***как человек уже пожилой и, по-видимому, искренно верующий*** обособляется, так как имеет значение причины.

Comment: Как Вы думаете, возможна ли конструкция _я пойду к батюшке поговорю_ (без запятой)?

Answer (score 0):

> ...*разъяснит* хоть немного *да* как человек уже пожилой и,
>   по-видимому, искренно верующий, *даст*, может быть, добрый совет.

При перечислении стоит союз, его достаточно — «разъяснит да даст», да и «как» никак нельзя отнести к сравнительному обороту: выделение чисто авторское.

Comment: Перед "да" согласна, запятая не нужна, а вот "как человек уже пожилой и, по-видимому, искренно верующий " - всё-таки обособленное приложение с КАК - будучи человеком пожилым. Вы же оставили вторую запятую(после верующий), а почему первую убрали? Нелогично.

Comment: «... по-видимому, искренно верующий» —  к этому обороту я бы относил запятую.

Comment: В смысле " уже пожилой и, по-видимому, искренно верующий" - причастный оборот? Но тогда должна быть запятая после определяемого слова человек, однако в данном случае, по-моему,  это не причастный оборот, "человек пожилой и верующий" - это приложение к батюшке, после слова человек запятая никак не нужна, там нет прич. оборота

Comment: Ваша правда, формально — причастного нет, а пауза налицо, и я бы её оставил, понимая, что в этом есть противоречие.

Comment: Потому и пауза после "верующий", что это конец обособленного распространённого приложения, выраженного конструкцией с как (батюшка - он же человек пожилой и верующий или батюшка, будучи человеком пожилым и верующим), а начало его - после да: ...разъяснит хоть немного да, как человек уже пожилой и, по-видимому, искренно верующий, даст...

Comment: Признать оборот без пяти минут деепричастным невозможно также.

Comment: Да при чём здесь деепричастный? Почему не хотите признать приложением? Обособленное приложение может присоединяться союзом как (с дополнительным значением причинности) и др., напр: Илюше иногда, как резвому мальчику, так и хочется броситься и переделать всё самому (Гончаров); Мне, как лицу высокопоставленному, не подобает ездить на конке… (Чехов); https://pravopisanie_i_stilistika.academic.ru/94/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F